# Java LinkedHashMap not maintaing the order of insert when looped in Play Framework 2.0 template

Tags: java, collections, playframework-2.0, linkedhashmap, scala-template

In play framework's (2.0) application controller I am creating a java 
`LinkedHashMap<String, List<MyObject>)` to maintain the order in which I am inserting the string key.

I tried iterating this LinkedHashMap in template like below:-

```
@for(currentKey <- linkedHashMapInstance.keySet()){
 ....
   loop  myObjectList for the currentKey
 ....
}
```

I got random order whenever I refresh the screen.

Then I tried to change the logic of looping by

```
@for((currentKey , currentList) <- mapOfCards){
 .. used the key and the list
}
```

Now I am getting a consistent order but not the order which I inserted..
The debug log in the server side is showing the correct order.

I was under assumption that LinkedHashMap in Java will maintain the order of inserts
even when it is rendered in a scala template.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Can you show te related Java code?

Comment: @alex 

    LinkedHashMap<String, List<MyObject>> mapOfCards = new     LinkedHashMap<String, List<MyObject>>();
    for (String myKey : someKeyList) {
    List<MyObject> objectList = ... populate list of my objects.
    mapOfCards.put(myKey, objectList);
    ... debug log in this line prints the right order of someKeyList
    }</code>

Answer (score 2):

It may be related to the Java->Scala conversion.

Try using `.asScala` like this:

```
@for((currentKey , currentList) <- mapOfCards.asScala){
 .. 
}
```

Update :

It works with:

```
@for((currentKey , currentList) <- scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap.empty[String, String] ++ mapOfCards) {

}
```

Comment: mapOfCards.asScala has no impact on the result

Answer (score 2):

I've faced the same issue a few months ago. As @nico_ekito pointed out, it's a problem related to the Java->Scala conversion.

To fix it, try something like this:

```
@for((currentKey , currentList) <- SortedMap.empty[String, String] ++ mapOfCards) {

}
```

by replacing `[String, String]` by the types of your `(currentKey , currentList)`.

Hope that helps, it worked for me.